# PHP Cannot Run Soap Function from wsdl file

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, client, not-exists

Hi am trying to run a function from wsdl. How to run this function?
When i am running get functions i am getting this

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(797) "ClientSoap createClient(string $client_name, string $client_password, string $first_name, string $last_name)"  }
```

I want to run the createClient function .
I already tried using this code

```
$client = new SoapClient('mywsdl.wsdl');
$data = $client->createClient("samplecustomer", "samplepass", "first", "last");
print_r($data);
```

I am getting an error that createClient does not exist. Any ides?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can help you but you can add a try catch surround the declaration.

```
    try {
       $soapClient = new \SoapClient($url. '?wsdl', $options);
    } catch (\SoapFault $e) { 
       print_r($e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: just tried it and i am getting again No such operation 'createClient'

Comment: Ho sorry, I think parameters doesn't match your service.
You must use array parameters. [Here an example](https://gist.github.com/akalongman/56484900eaf19b18cfbd)

Comment: Hi ..i tried it also with array but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: the only message i am getting is this No such operation 'createClient'